# Is multidimensional structure possible in C++?

Tags: c++, struct

Remember I am talking about multidimensional STRUCTURES and not multidimensional arrays, STRUCTURE VARIABLES, etc.
If yes, then what is the syntax?
The example will help you clear things out:

```
struct arr[3]{
    int a, float b,
    int c, float d,
    int e, float f;
}
```

I just used the syntax that are used for multidimensional arrays with some additional work (like semicolon after the last variable) which is not used as a syntax for multidimensional arrays. AND
Don't think this as an actual syntax, here I am just trying to let you understand my question.
A multidimensional structure which has two types of data in one row separated by columns. A one which can have different type of data in each rows.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I might have called it a pretty good question if were able to understand what you want to achieve. How about create code with example use case of your idea?

Comment: Is this a C or C++ question? In C you'd use an array of arrays. In C++ a `std::vector` with a `std::vector` in it.

Comment: I am sure that I want a multidimensional structure

Comment: But we still don't know what a "multidimensional structure" is :-(

Comment: @tadman: as the title says C++, I removed that tag.

Comment: This is C++. Or I am fine if this feature available in C

Comment: That is not a valid C++ syntax. There are multidimensional arrays and containers of containers if you prefer.

Comment: @DarshanGupta - could you describe the semantics of a "multidimensional structure?" Since no such beast currently exists by the name, maybe if you tell us what it does, we could help you find a solution.

Comment: One minute let me explain.

Comment: "I am sure that I want a multidimensional structure " - we don't understand what you mean by "multidimensional structure".

Comment: Please have a look at this [C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) list and a very well maintained [C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/).

Comment: If this question is "can I have a structure with a bunch of properties and then make an array of that so there's two levels to the structure" then the answer is yes.

Comment: Take an example of multidimensional array in which each row has elements of same datatype. Each column holds the data of same type. Now in the case of multidimensional structure I am asking a structure in which each row has elements of different datatype. However, each column will store same type of data

Comment: Hope this helps

Comment: Sounds like an array of struct...

Comment: *"I am asking a structure in which each row has elements of different datatype. However, each column will store same type of data"* Well, there are no columns in a class or at least its members aren't organized in that way. But you can declare multiple variables with the same type: `struct arr { int a, c, e; float b, d, f; };`

Comment: I believe, he wants a 2d array where the first dimension will be an `integer` and the second a `float`. Something like a `php` array where you don't need to declare the type of the variable, although in `cpp` you have to.

Comment: I don't understand much but I believe you are right @Seg

Comment: I have pasted a link in my question open that image and it might help you guys

Comment: You can make a struct that holds an array of ints and holds an array of chars.

Comment: @DarshanGupta you want a two dimensional array that the first column will have variables of type `int` and the second of type `float`. For example: `array[0][0]` would have an `int` and `array[0][1]` would have a `float`. Am i right?

Comment: Yup but you should not store things like: houseno, roll number of the student, etc. informations together as they look odd, so here you must declare two-three variables @christian

Comment: @Segmentation yes but in the form of two dimensional structure

Comment: Use an array of union instead of struct, and be very disciplined when using this thingy. ;-)

Comment: @alk union shares memory which I don't want.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by it looking odd to group information together.

Comment: You should take a look at C++17 `std::variant`. It allows you have an array that the data type varies.

Comment: What would you name an array which stores info like houseno, barcode_no, employee number?

Comment: Sorry guys I am running out of battery right now and my charger sucks, further it is night here so bye see you soon

Comment: @DarshanGupta I would call it structure.

Comment: This definitely feels like an XY problem.  The best I can guess is that what you really need is an array of structs, but unless you can give us more information about what it is you are actually trying to accomplish, the all we can do is guess at what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

An array of structs seems to satisfy your request. The

```
#include <iostream>
static struct { int a; float b; } arr[2] = {1, 1.5, 2, 2.5};

int main () {
    // Print the value of the first column 
    std::cout << "Column 'a': " <<
        arr[0].a << " " <<
        arr[1].a << "\n";

    // Print the value of the first row
    std::cout << "Row '0': " <<
        arr[0].a << " " <<
        arr[0].b << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, not sorry @Rob I know this thing

Comment: Wait guys I am making a word document which might help you

Comment: Robs solution does exactly what you want.

Comment: @Rob the program you gave is similar to what I want. Just print 0 (as an int) twice, once from each of the first two "columns".

Comment: @DarshanGupta - I've updated my answer. Does this describe what you are looking for?